What model to use for multivariable analysis with small sample size
I have a small sample size of around 350 of which around 20 or so had an event. I have around 12 variables that might be associated with the event and hoping to do multivariant analysis, some of which also have small number around 10. I'm keen to know 1 particular variable and if it has a significant impact on the event taking consideration into the others.
Which statistics model should I use? I think the simple logistic regression my event size is too small.

Addendum
Thank you for your input. What I wanted to do is to perform an analysis with multiple variables. I want to see if one particular variable X (which is categorical data) would affect the risk of the event happening or not (hoping for output of odds ratio). But I know that there is another 11 variable known to contribute to the even, so I want to see if taking consideration of all other variables influencing, whether X have a significant effect on the event. Does that make it clearer?
Thank your!

Greetings and welcome to CV! Could you clarify what your purpose here is? Are you trying to predict an outcome (with presumably LR) or are you testing some specific theory? 20 variables is a lot, and with few events happening, less is probably more. So it would be good to know what your ultimate goal is here with this model.

Could you please explain what you mean by "multivariant analysis"?

Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find
information on how to do this in the My Account
section of our [help]), then you will be able to
edit & comment on your own question.

The standard term for using multiple explanatory variables in regression is [tag:multiple-regression].  The standard method to obtain estimates of odds ratios is logistic regression.  Neither imposes any mathematical limits on the numbers of variables or observations, but the numbers needed to be effective or meaningful depends on the context and the nature of the data.

As noted in the comments, multiple logistic regression, and indeed regression in general doesn't limit the number of observations or predictors, but there are technical limits. Your question boils down to a few related things:

Sample size and parameters: there are many good sources of information on this, including Frank Harrell's book. A quick quote from his website: "a model must fit no more than $\frac{m}{15}$ parameters for it to be reliable on future similar patients, where $m$ is the effective sample size." This is in the context of predictive models, but works in general.
Events per predictor: a good Cross Validated question and answer is here (see other good questions and answers in the comment under the question). This is related to Harrell's quote as well.
Estimation, model selection and hypothesis testing: your number of predictors is probably too large, especially if ALL the predictors are categorical, given your stated number of events. Beyond having a small effective sample size, you can have problems with sparse data that can lead to separation. It seems you have a focal predictor (one of most interest) which is good, and that you want to add the others as statistical controls. Thus, you have a clear estimand (a comparison of adjusted odds of the event in one group v. another, or as associated with a particular predictor) and a model that can potentially give you a good estimate, and for which you can test the default null hypothesis. However, you may have issues, and if you need all the covariates (for substantive reasons), you will probably need to fit the model with a penalized method. It is generally not advisable to adjust your model (remove predictors) after seeing the resulting estimates and p-values. If you must do so, this is more complicated and would require methods to remove the resulting bias in the subsequent tests.


The problem in this case is that the effective sample size m in an event-based (or binomial) model is the number of events (or the number of cases in the minority class), not the total sample size. So in the OP we have m=20, not m=350. Some penalization will be necessary to avoid overfitting, if one wants to include more than 1 or maybe 2 predictors. It might be possible to include the 1 predictor of primary interest and use an L2 (ridge) penalty on the others.

For sure. I was mainly speaking to a basic version of what OP was trying to do without recommending penalization right away but I will remove the recommendation about throwing them all in
